# select rows with null value python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I select the rows with null values in respect of columns name?

#### What I have:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 2 |  | v |
| 3 | y |  |
| 4 | w | j |
| 5 | w |  |

#### What I want:

Select rows with null in respect with e.g. column `B`:

| ID | B |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | y |
| 5 | w |

Comment: why 2 not selected?

Comment: Because I want to select the null values only in column `B`!

Comment: `df[df['B'].isna()]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [`pandas.Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
>>> df
   ID    A    B
0   1    a    b
1   2  NaN    v
2   3    y  NaN
3   4    w    j
4   5    w  NaN

>>> df[df.pop('B').isna()]

   ID  A
2   3  y
4   5  w
```

Use `pop` if you do not need column `'B'` in the original dataframe afterwards. Otherwise, use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
>>> df[df['B'].isna()].drop('B', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use isna() or isnull() functions.

df[df['column name'].isna()]

(or)

df[df['column name'].isnull()]